# Select multiple files but capture them one at the time

Tags: php

I building a functionality where the user can select select multiple files submit them. Each file on average is about 3mb but I have a memory limit of about 32MB (and we will not go beyond that). The problem is that I want to give the ability to the user to select as many file as they want (on average they can select at most 11 at once) but since my limit is 32mb they can't so it got me thinking. Is it possible for the user the select as many file as they want (with the assumption that not of them are bigger than 32mb) but capturing them individually (so giving the impression that only one file is submitted at the time)? Initially when I built my code I thought the 32mb was for one file only (not the total amount file). How can I achieve this with the code I already have?

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
/* error_reporting(0);   
$dir=substr(uniqid(),-7); */

/* error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 */


   // do your Db stuff here to get t
  $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "jpeg");
$max_file_size =        32768*32000; //32000 kb


/* $path = "Prototype/uploads/"; // Upload directory
mkdir ($path, 0744); */
$count = 0;

    $skippedimages = new SplQueue();
    $imported = new SplQueue();

if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    // Loop $_FILES to exeicute all files

    var_dump($_FILES);

    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {   


        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {


          continue; // Skip file if any error found
            //echo "something <br>";
        }          
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {              
            if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                //echo "something***************** <br>";
                continue; // Skip large files
            }
            elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
                $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                //echo "something+++++++++++++++++++ <br>";
                //echo "$name-- ";
                continue; // Skip invalid file formats
            }
            else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files 
              //  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name))
               // $count=$count+1; // Number of successfully uploaded file

                //echo $path.$name;

                 $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$f]));

                $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['files']['name'][$f]);

                $ext = pathinfo($image_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                $withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $image_name);

                $XXXXX= $withoutExt;


            $flag = false;  
            $query = "Select * from $dbname.XXXX
                               where XXXX= '$XXXX'"; 
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

            $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);

            if($rowcount>0){



                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


                    $ID =  $row['*****'];
                    $query2 = "*******";     
                    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$query2);
                    if(!$result2){

                        continue;
                    }else{

                        $flag =true;
                    }


                }

            if($flag) {
                ++$count; 
                $withoutExt .= "-$count";
                $imported->push($withoutExt);
                }





            }else{


            }
             //Number of successfully uploaded file

            }
        }
    }

    echo "<h3>$count files were imported <h3>";





  }




    //show success message


?>
```

Comment: as php will handle all files uploaded i suggest you use ajax that submits the files one each time.

Comment: better check the maximum size already at client side, before uploading!

Comment: @Bobby, [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38994152/upload-multiple-files-one-by-one-using-dropzone-js)

Comment: @Jeff, I think It's a great idea because the application keeps crashing when we try uploading big files. But how can I check that?

Comment: @Bobby http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133870/check-filesize-before-upload